# Woocommerce Rest API (PHP) - add existing tags to existing product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I've tried many variations of this but cannot seem to be able to add existing tags to an existing product via the api.

I'm currently trying:

```
$myTagPut = ['tags' => ['id' => 216], ['id' => 222]];
$woocommerce->put('products/'.$prod->id, $myTagPut);
```

There are no errors of any kind when this runs, but it also isn't adding the tags to the product.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've also tried just a comma separated list of tag ids, adding all of the tag information (i.e. name, etc.) in the call and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a syntax issue as the following code worked:

```
$myTagPut = ['tags' => [['id' => 216,],['id' => 222,],],];
$woocommerce->put('products/'.$prod->id, $myTagPut);
```